# How to see SQLite database in ionic?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have used the cordovaSQLite plugin for using DB in ionic framework.
Do we have any UI for the same where I can see the database and see the tables and its entries.?

I have used the SQLite app for native android development but nothing I can find for ionic (Cordova) yet.
Any Help?

Comment: Hi, I'm also searching for this, did you find any solution